# how to know the spark application's parent application in oozie spark action

Tags: hadoop, oozie

when I use oozie's spark action launch a spark application, oozie will first launch a mapreduce applicaton, then the mapreduce launch a spark application. How can I know a spark application is launched by which mapreduce task?

So far I can see MapReduce application is named with some oozie information, like  `oozie:launcher:T=spark:W=JavaWordCount:A=spark-test:ID=0000023-171207132348866-oozie-oozi-W`, and the spark application has a application tags like `oozie-6e83d420c018bc0f63bccd19fe73b24f`.But I still don't konw how to associate them?

Comment: Look inside the YARN logs for the Oozie Launcher container. You should see, among the verbose Spark driver output, the ID of the spawned YARN app that runs the executors.

Comment: yep, I see the information in the log. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the spark application-id by using yarn client:

1. to show all application-id and get the oozie:launcher mapreduce application-id please run the following command;

yarn application -list

2. then you can get the spark application id by using the oozie:launcher mapreduce application-id like this:

yarn logs -applicationId $APPID | grep "Submitted application" | awk '{print $NF}'

please change $APPID by the first mapreduce application-id which launch the spark application